# VSTO add-in for Outlook 2016

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I have a vsto add-in for outlook developed in Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0), but now when I tried to add this add-in for Outlook 2016 it is showing invalid vsto add-in. My question is:

Can the VSTO solution developed in Visual Studio 2010/12 support in Outlook 2016?

If not then what's the alternate or if yes then what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

A VSTO add-in should be installed on the machine. At least you need to add the required windows registry entries to load the add-in, you can't just add it. See [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins) and [Registry Entries for VSTO Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/registry-entries-for-vsto-add-ins) for more information.

> My question is 'Can the vsto solution developed in Visual Studio 2010/12 support in Outlook 2016?'

Yes, it can. See [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/running-solutions-in-different-versions-of-microsoft-office). It states the following:

*Microsoft Office applications can also run solutions created by using previous versions of Visual Studio. In some cases, these solutions require different versions of the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime. Different versions of the Visual Studio Tools for Office runtime can be installed side-by-side on the same computer.*

I'd suggest creating an installer which can check for preprequsites if any, add the required windows registry keys and install the plug-in on the system.

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-windows-installer)
- [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-an-office-solution-by-using-clickonce)